# .mp4 video plays in Safari desktop but NOT Safari iPad

Tags: macos, video, safari, ipad, video-codecs

I'm redoing my website with HTML5 video and have it working fine on the desktop already.

However, on the iPad, it loads, but does not play. For the video I'm using the iPad defaults in Adobe Media Encoder as a starting point, with a 'level' of 3.1.

Here is my URL: http://bitstream.ca/. The Safari version on the desktop is 5.11.

Comment: Please post your *exact* settings in Adobe Media Encoder. Also, which version of Media Encoder do you use? See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW9) for all supported profiles for video on iOS Safari.

Comment: Have you found any other websites that can do what you are expecting to work on your iPad with HTML5 output? (use http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbitstream.ca%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0   ) against them to check

Comment: I had this problem once and I had to uninstall Safari and reinstall it with the quickTime bundle to get MP4 to work. I don't remember if that was on a PC or the iPad, but you might want to try it.